# How to use iCloud Keychain instead of login keychain

Tags: keychain, iterm2, coda

I would like to use iCloud Keychain for everything, but some applications, like Coda 2, Transmit, iTerm2 and others "insist" in using the default Login keychain. If I want to store passwords in iCloud I need to duplicate them. Even worst, I can copy from login keychain to iCloud Keychain, but not from iCloud to login.

I wonder if I can force the system to use iCloud for all.

Any suggestion?